# How do I make sure that only one action runs in response to user input?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Say an app has two buttons and each starts an animation (eg. a push or other standard segue or custom animation). How do you stop both animations from happening simultaneously if the user presses both buttons “at once”? Well, first I tried:

```
[[viewController view] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

But this doesn't fix the problem. (Maybe `userInteractionEnabled` is not cascaded to subviews immediately?)

Then I tried:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Which does fix the problem, *except* if you press both buttons *very* quickly, one after the other (basically press both at the same time using 2 fingers), then you get both animations happening which causes problems for my app. Maybe both events have already triggered before my code to run `-beginIgnoringInteractionEvents` gets called?

What is a reliable way to immediately stop any other tap events? Or flush out ones that have  started already. I have this problem all over my app - pressing two buttons (or tapping table cells etc) very quickly triggers two events and messes up animations.

Any ideas? What do people do about this problem in iOS apps?

Comment: why don't you add a property like isAnimating and check for its state after button pressed and before your animation?

Comment: when click on button check is there any animation ,if animation found then stop that one and start new animation.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, but I have lots of animations throughout my app including standard push/pop segues etc. So I would have to have some sort of global isAnimating property and even set it during all my standard segues! (which is hard to do as it has to be unset on completion of the animations). There must be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Touch handling is done asynchronously in iOS to make sure the device is responsive. This means that handlers might be queued up before being run, which is the reason why your call to `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents` is being ignored.

The easiest solution is to simply create a global variable to make interactions exclusive yourself.

```
@interface UIApplicaiton(AnimationsInProgress)

- (BOOL)isAnimationInProgress;
- (void)setAnimationInProgress:(BOOL)value;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation UIApplication(AnimationsInProgress)
{
    BOOL _isAnimationInProgress;
}

- (BOOL)isAnimationInProgress {
    return _isAnimationInProgress;
}

- (void)setAnimationInProgress:(BOOL)value {
    _isAnimationInProgress = value;
}
```

Use it almost like you would `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents`, at the top of your animation actions:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isAnimationInProgress)
    return;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setAnimationInProgress:YES];

[UIView animate .... completion:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setAnimationInProgress:NO];
}];
```

As there is no race-condition like with the touch events and `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents`, this will work for your purpose.

Comment: OK that's helpful thanks. But what about standard iOS segues. I guess i could intercept prepareForSegue and call setAnimationInProgress, but  there's no easy, reliable way to know when the segue is complete I don't think.

Comment: For segues, keep track of it in the view controller itself, set a state boolean in `prepareForSegue` and reset it in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: I'm not sure it's 100% reliable though, that viewDidAppear will always be paired with every prepareForSegue. If anything gets out of sync I'm going to be left with a dead app (animations blocked). (Also, thanks to zoul for tidying up my question :)